# Does the Mann-Whitney U-test need to be adjusted in twin studies?

Tags: statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, paired-data, adjustment, ecology

I have data from 44 twin pairs (88 patients total) and they are split into `group_A` (n=50) and `group_B` (n=38).  For each of the patients, I have attribute data (Let's say m=100) so my data matrix is `(n=88, m=100)`.  I have properly normalized the data and used the `Mannwhitney U-test` for each attribute using `group_A` and `group_B`. I have p-values associated with each of the attributes.  **My question, do I need to account for the twin aspect in this calculation or is there no need?**  If so, how would one do this? I used hierarchical clustering to look at the beta diversity and in some cases twins from the same family cluster by each other and in other cases they don't.

I'm using this function from [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html) where $x$ is $attribute_j$ of `group_A` and $y$ is $attribute_j$ of `group_B` in my implementation.

Patients from `group_A` do not overlap with patients from `group_B`.  group_A has a disease and group_B has a healthy phenotype. My objective is to see which attributes have distributions that are significantly different between the 2 groups.

Comment: Are twins in the same group, or different groups?

Comment: The groups are mutually exclusive so no individual in group_a (healthy) will be in group_b (disease) .  There are also have MZ and DZ twin pairs.

Comment: This gives you more power - you have a partially matched analysis.

Comment: What is your grouping criteria and m= 100 ? Also state your objectives?

Comment: `group_A` has a disease and `group_B` has a healthy phenotype.  My objective is to see which attributes have distributions that are significantly different between the 2 groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it depends on whether a twin's score is similar to their co-twin's score. If this is the case, you have violated the independence assumption, and your p-value will not be correct.

Think of an extreme example: Twins always have the same score as their co-twin. If this is the case, you don't have a sample where n = 88, your sample is really n = 44 (because when you know a twin's score, you know the second score, hence no information is added by the second twin.

You need to take into account this non-independence - there are a few ways to do it, e.g. using survey estimates, clustered standard errors, gee, hierarchical linear models. You might have an additional problem that you have MZ and DZ twins, so the degree of violation varies in a predictable way. Gelman recently blogged about this: http://andrewgelman.com/2017/12/27/id-say-robust-standard-errors-like-holy-roman-empire-except-think-theyre-error/

Comment: This is very helpful.  What about if some cases the twin scores are similar and in other cases the twin scores are not.  The grouping sometimes has both individuals of a twin pair and sometimes the twins are split into the 2 groups.

Comment: If the twins are in different groups, it's less of an issue - it can actually increase your power because the individuals in the groups are matched (or partially matched).